# Setting up sharepoint for access through internet

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, alternate-access-mapping, dns, web-application-zones

I have SP2013 set up in VMs on 1 server. I have 3 VMs: DC, SQL, SP (192.168.1.130)

My internal domain is klab.com and but I bought a domain on godaddy called myname.com

My static IP is 60.60.60.30 so I created a record in GoDaddy that points myname.com to 60.60.60.30

In CAm on the web app I created an Alternative Access Mapping in the Internet Zone for "myname.com" and in IIS I created the binding for it. I reset IIS (just in case).

However, I can't get "myname.com" to point to SP (192.168.1.130). I assume I need to do something in DNS but I'm not sure what exactly. Do I need a whole new Forward Lookup zone and set the A record there?

Comment: Check this http://serverfault.com/questions/301103/correct-way-to-setup-my-dns-on-godaddy-to-work-with-rackserver

Comment: I got it working by creating a new forward lookup zone for myname.com

Answer (score 0):

To access the site by example.com, you will need to add a DNS Host (A) record for the  site.